# Is 'repeat' a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I often hear this:

"Can you repeat?"

shouldn't it be

"Can you repeat that?"

Question: is it incorrect to not put an object after 'repeat'? Maybe that is just 'slang' or such slips are acceptable in informal conversations?

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly what you've heard?  In what context?  It doesn't sound like normal US English usage.  That said, yes, people do sometimes leave things out in informal speech.

Comment: **Please repeat** and **Can/will you (please) repeat** are common in conversational English.

Comment: What @RonaldSole said. But I note this from [Telephone and Helpdesk Skills: **A Guide to Professional English**:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t+say+%27repeat+please%22) - *Don't say '**repeat please**'*. Nevertheless, I certainly wouldn't dismiss the "intransitive" usage as "slangy", or "slip-of-the-tongue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that “repeat” in this context is a transitive verb. Thus an object is grammatically required.

However, in speech or informal writing, what is grammatically required is sometimes implied rather than explicitly stated, particularly when the speaker believes that what is implied is obvious.

With that said, this example is quite sloppy. A reasonable proportion of the time, it will elicit the response “Repeat what exactly?” The omission of the object thus wastes time rather than saves time.

I also point out that the use of “can” may interfere with effective communication. True story. My wife recently sent a contractor an email saying “Can you provide references.” The email back saying “Yes” merely delayed getting contact information for references. My wife was not amused that I was audibly amused.

> Will you please repeat that order number

is more likely to lead to a pleasant and quick phone call than either

> Can you repeat?

or the perfectly grammatical

> Can you repeat that?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/), **repeat** can be both transitive and intransitive, though it does not, in my opinion, provide any satisfactory examples of intransitive uses.

For intransitive uses, the thing that is repeated is the subject, for example:

> A chorus in an average pop song **repeats** at least four times. - *Music Production - Michael Zager 2012*

For transitive uses, the agent is the subject and the thing that is repeated is the object:

> As he repeats the musical phrase he repeats the series of physical moves involved in its playing and vocalizes under the notes - *Glenn: a play, David Young, 1999*

Telling somebody to repeat something must be a transitive usage, because the person who is to repeat it is the subject. I would not say "please repeat" without providing an object, but I can imagine others doing so. They would justify this by saying that the object is implicitly clear. This would make it some kind of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), though not one of the widely used and therefore well documented ones.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in thinking that there needs to be an object, but informally it would be acceptable to ask someone to repeat what they said by saying "Can you repeat?". It's more of a slip up that a conversational partner would be inclined to ignore.

"Can you repeat that?" is definitely more correct. As a very polite Australian, I would also apologize before asking someone to repeat something. "Sorry, say again?" is my go to. Again this is *technically* incorrect, but informally it's acceptable. It's more of a habit that I acquired from years of using radios to communicate.